# Map array of objects in array of parent objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am having trouble mapping an array of objects (comments) in array of parent objects (requests) from JSON via RestKit's mapping functionality.

All my data returns properly, but for some reason the comment objects are never populated!

See my code below:

**request.json:**

```
{
    "data": {
        "priorityRequests": [
            {
                "id": 123456,
                "title": "Request 1",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "author": "John Smith",
                        "content": "This is a comment"
                    }, {
                        "author": "Jane Smith",
                        "content": "This is another comment"
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "id": 654321,
                "title": "Request 2",
                "comments": [
                    {
                        "author": "John Smith",
                        "content": "This is a comment"
                    }, {
                        "author": "Jane Smith",
                        "content": "This is another comment"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Comment.h/m**

```
@interface Comment : NSObject

@property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSString *author;
@property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSString *content;

@end

@implementation Comment

@end
```

**Request.h/m**

```
@import "Request.h"

@interface Request : NSObject

@property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSString *id;
@property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSString *title;
@property ( strong, nonatomic ) Comment *comments;

@end

@implementation Request

@end
```

**RequestManager.m snippet**

```
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [ RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: [ Request class ] ];
[ requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id" : @"id",
    @"title" : @"versionNumber"
}];

RKObjectMapping *commentMapping = [ RKObjectMapping mappingForClass: [ Comment class ] ];
[ commentMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"title": @"title",
    @"author": @"author"
}];

// Failed attempt 1:
[ requestMapping addPropertyMapping: [ RKRelationshipMapping 
    relationshipMappingFromKeyPath: @"comments"
    toKeyPath: @"comments"
    withMapping: commentMapping ] 
];
// end

// Failed attempt 2:
RKRelationshipMapping* requests_comments = [ RKRelationshipMapping 
    relationshipMappingFromKeyPath: @"comments" 
    toKeyPath: @"comments" 
    withMapping: commentMapping 
];

[ requestMapping addPropertyMapping: requests_comments ];
// end
```

**RequestCommunicator.m snippet**

```
NSDictionary *mappingsDictionary = @{ "data.priorityRequest" : requestMapping };

RKMapperOperation *mapper = [ [ RKMapperOperation alloc ] 
    initWithRepresentation: parsedData // parsed json as above
    mappingsDictionary: mappingsDictionary 
];

NSError *mappingError = nil;

BOOL isMapped = [ mapper execute: &mappingError ];

// If no errors, returned array of mapped objects
if (isMapped && !mappingError) {

    // All data except for comments here
    // _comments = (Comment *) nil
    [ self.delegate receivedResponseObject: [ mapper mappingResult ].array ];

    ... etc.
```

Comment: Can't see an obvious fault in the code. Turn on trace logging and see where it mentions comments.

Comment: @Wain Will do, thanks for the little edit too, oversight

Comment: @Wain In the stack trace, RKMapperOperation > _mutableMappingInfo - there are two fields, _mutablePropertyMappings (all of the Request mappings) and _mutableRelationshipMappings (comment mappings). The second one returns 2 objects in fact (so I'm assuming it's getting the comments!) although not sure why they aren't carrying across though with the mappingResult...

Comment: I've confirmed that the comment above stands true, I tried a bunch of varying comment amounts and all of the numbers came through in the stack trace in the mutableMappingInfo branch. This is odd as to why it's not being associated with the array of objects. I've even tried things in the mapping dict such as: @"comments.title": @"title", @"(comments)title": @"title", @"(comments).title": @"title" to no avail.

Comment: So the comments are created. But in `mapper mappingResult` you don't see the comments. What about in the `comments` property on the mapped `Request`?

Comment: Correct. I assign Request as [ mapper mappingResult ].array - which is why the comments are nil, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You should very rarely use the mapping result array (use dictionary instead) and what is the request you assign? I'm not clear how you are testing for comments.

Comment: @Wain I agree, I was going to sort that out later, I had a delegate expecting an array for the time being. I got this working and I'll add my findings shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix to this issue, and although it might not be everyone's cup of tea, hopefully it can help someone else down the track.

In my Requests NSObject, I changed the mapping from type 'Comment' to 'NSArray':

```
- @property ( strong, nonatomic ) Comment *comments;
+ @property ( strong, nonatomic ) NSArray *comments;
```

Comment: Not about cups of tea, that is the correct solution.